# MacBook Pro needs to be reminded that it has a full battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

About once a day, I'll shut the lid on my MacBook Pro (*15" 2015, still going strong!*) with plenty of battery charge and when I open it up again, it will flash the *low battery* image. It's a big fat liar though... it has plenty of juice left.

To fix, I plug the MagSafe connector in for like 3 seconds until it gets past the *low battery* screen. Then I can unplug the MagSafe and I'm fine... battery is back at 75% (or whatever) and will run normally.

What gives? Any ideas? I already tried recalibrating, PRAM, and SMC resets.

Note: It's actually a new battery, was replaced maybe 6 months ago.

Comment: Is it the original 7-year-old battery? How many cycles has it done? There comes a point when the power management can't accurately gauge old batteries.

Comment: @benwiggy It's actually a new battery. Was replaced maybe 6 months ago.

Comment: A genuine Apple replacement, or something from eBay?

Comment: Definitely not genuinely from Apple. Ha!

Comment: Did this behavior begin when the battery was changed, or at a later time?

Comment: It's a new problem... although I just recently upgraded the MacBook from Catina to Monterey (skipped Big Sur). Think that has something to do with it?